# Imported Array with react map function but `undefined`

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
Object: 
    Info: Array(2) 
        0:
               > minsuInfo: Array(2) 
               
                 0: 
                    > dailyValue(2) :
                       0: Status: 20%
                       1: Status: 40% 
                    
                 1:  
                    > dailyValue(2):        
                       0: Status: 40%
                       1: Status: 15%

         1:  
                   > minsuInfo: Array(2) 
                 0: 
                    > dailyValue(2) :
                       0: Status: 60%
                       1: Status: 10% 
                    
                 1:  
                    > dailyValue(2):        
                       0: Status: 40%
                       1: Status: 55%
```

```
const apple = Info.minsuInfo.map(array => array.dailyValue.Status) 

return (
<div>
<p>{apple}</p> // undefined 
</div>
)
```

I want to print all `Status` values.
`const apple = Info.minsuInfo.map(array => array.dailyValue.Status)`

I expected this. 
`console.log(apple) // 20% 40% 40% 15% 60% 10% 40% 55%`

But now I get `undefined` .
`console.log(apple) // undefined`

How should I modify the code?

Comment: Can you please update your post to include an updated structure of your data so that it is valid js?

Comment: @NickParsons It's corrected.

Comment: Can you update this part: `Object: 
    Info: Array(2) 
        0:` so that it's valid JS, such as `{Info: [/* rest of your data */]}`. The issue is that this can't be copied into a JS file, so it makes it difficult to debug and provide runnable examples with the data you've given.

Comment: @NickParsons 
The arrangement is like this.